# Dynamic rescue clauses, how does this code work?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, metaprogramming

```
def errors_matching(&block)
  m = Module.new
  (class << m ;self; end).instance_eval do
    define_method(:===, &block)
  end
  m
end
```

This allows me to define dynamic rescue clauses in Ruby, for example:

```
begin
  raise 'hi'
rescue errors_matching { |e| e.class.name.include?('Runtime') } => e
  puts "Ignoring #{e.message}"
end
```

I don't understand the first piece of code. What's the whole point of m = Module.new and then putting self (which is main in this case) inside a singleton class and doing instance_eval on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
class << m; self end
```

is obviously the same as:

```
m.singleton_class
```

And

```
m.singleton_class.instance_eval { define_method(:foo) {} }
```

is just the same as

```
m.define_singleton_method(:foo) {}
```

So, the whole `errors_matching` method is just a very convoluted way of saying:

```
def errors_matching(&block)
  Module.new.tap do |m| m.define_singleton_method(:===, &block) end
end
```

Comment: A word of clarification: The OP contacted me privately and pointed me to this post. The original code is from Exceptional Ruby, which I wrote. That book was written to be mostly compatible with 1.8.7, where `define_singleton_method` didn't exist. And `tap` was brand new in 1.8.7 and not as well-known.